# Window Manager With Null Token

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, custom-view, android-windowmanager

Below is the code which i am using to add a view

```
fun showPanel(context: Context) {
        if (!AccessibilityUtils.checkAccessibilityEnabled()) {
            LogUtils.d("no Accessibility permission")
            showToast(context, "Please grant the permission.")
            return
        }
        val windowManager by lazy { context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager }
        if (floatPanelView != null) {
            LogUtils.d("floatPanelView has been initialized")
            if (floatPanelView?.isAttachedToWindow == true) {
                LogUtils.d("floatPanelView has been attached")
            } else {
                LogUtils.d("floatPanelView hasn't been attached")
                windowManager.addView(floatPanelView, floatPanelView?.params)
            }
            return
        }
        LogUtils.d("init floatPanelView")
        floatPanelView = FloatPanelView(context)
        floatPanelView?.params =
            WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY)
                .apply {
                    format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888
                    flags =
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP
                    width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    // Set it as 1/4 in vertical
                    y = ScreenUtils.getScreenHeight() / 4
                }
        LogUtils.d("params.y: ${floatPanelView?.params?.y}")
        MainActivity.isServiceRunning.postValue(true)
        windowManager.addView(floatPanelView, floatPanelView?.params)
    }
```

and i am getting the below crashes in my app

> Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add
> window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1274)
> android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:409)
> android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
> com.iobits.tech.autotapper.presentation.views.MyWindowManager.showPanel(MyWindowManager.kt:96)
> com.iobits.tech.autotapper.service.FloatWindowService.onStartCommand(FloatWindowService.kt:52)
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4694)
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2226)
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)

The service class from where actually calling this is as below

```
class FloatWindowService : LifecycleAccessibilityService(), LifecycleEventObserver {
    private val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1241

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        logd(intent?.action.toString())
        logd("mStartService")
        // Create a notification and start the service in the foreground
        if (intent?.action == "STOP_SERVICE") {
            logd("stopping service")
            stopSelf()
            stopForeground(true)

//            disableSelf() to stop the service from settings
            MyWindowManager.release(this)
//            this.stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE) // Stop the service whe/n the stop button is clicked
            return START_NOT_STICKY
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            ServiceCompat.startForeground(
                this,
                NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification(), ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_NONE
            )
            logd("mStartServices")

        } else {
            this.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification())
        }
        if (intent?.hasExtra("isSingle") == true) {
           try {
               MyWindowManager.showPanelWithOneOnly(this)

           } catch (e:Exception){
               logd("service not yet registered")
           }
        } else {
            try {

                MyWindowManager.showPanel(this)
            }catch (e:Exception){
                logd("service not yet registered")
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }
```